# Property 'value' is missing in type '{ searchValue: string; setSearchValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; }' but required in type 'Props'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using react native with typescript to render some movie posters from an API when the movie title is writen on the search bar. But when I try to render the search bar on my app I get this error:

Property 'value' is missing in type '{ searchValue: string; setSearchValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' but required in type 'Props'.

And under it:

Search.tsx(7, 5): 'value' is declared here.

Here is the App code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import MovieList from './components/MovieList'
import Search from './components/Search';
import { Container } from './styles'

const App: React.FC = () => {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

    const getMovieRequest = async (searchValue) => {
        const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=520a7faf`;

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const responseJson = await response.json();

        if (responseJson.Search) {
            setMovies(responseJson.Search);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovieRequest(searchValue);
    }, [searchValue]);

    console.log(movies);

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Search searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
                <ScrollView>
                    <MovieList movies={movies} />
                </ScrollView>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And the search bar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
    searchValue: string;
    setSearchValue:(string) => void;
    value: any;
}

const Search: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    return (
       <View>
           <TextInput 
           placeholder="Pesquise aqui"
           value={props.value}
           onChange={(event: any) => props.setSearchValue(event.target.value)}
           />
       </View>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Search` component has a prop called `value`, which is required. However, you're not passing `value` when rendering that component with `<Search searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />`.

You should either make the `value` prop optional, or make sure you always pass a value. To make it optional, you would change the props like this:

```ts
interface Props {
    searchValue: string;
    setSearchValue:(string) => void;
    value?: any; // <--- Note the ? on value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In search you are defined that your search components have this props so them are mandatory

```
interface Props {
    searchValue: string;
    setSearchValue:(string) => void;
    value: any;
}
```

So when you call Search component you should pass value prop, if you want to value to be optional you should add it to the interface with ? after a property

```
<Search searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} value={whatever}/>
```

```
interface Props {
    searchValue: string;
    setSearchValue:(string) => void;
    value?: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the `Search` component in App.tsx, you do not pass the `value` prop to Search but it is required. You need something like:

`<Search searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} value="value"/>`